# iOS Button not fully rendered after push transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a view controller that when a subclass UIButton is tapped, it pushes another view controller. The problem is that I have another button of the same subclass on the newly presented view controller but when it appears it's cut off.

This problem solves itself when I tap a keyboard key and if I tap "Debug View Hierarchy" it appears fully drawn in Xcode and when I exit debugging it's fully drawn.

Here's an example of the problem in an iPhone XS Max iOS 12.1 and Swift 4.2 (I've covered with a red rectangle some text fields since they have user details but they're are subclasses of UITextField and the card view is a child view controller with a UICollectionView):

This is what I get
[image: wide demo pic]

This is what I expect
[image: wide demo pic]

I have tried putting setNeedsDisplay and layoutIfNeeded for the button and its superview inside `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` but I haven't been able to determine what's happening and how to solve it. I would really appreciate if someone could help me. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check other UIWindows in view debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not a rendering issue and its another view on top of the button. Try more investigating in `view debugger`

[image: View debugger]

Then see what it is. (check other UIWindows)

I guess it's keyboard suggestion's view. or some footer view or etc.

Comment: Thank you. It was a weird keyboard view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keyboard’s ´inputAccessoryView´ is getting in the way.

You can try disabling it.